# Submit FORM data to a Single Page Application securely?

Tags: html, forms, reactjs, single-page-application

We have an uncommon situation due to a confluence of factors we would like an external application to submit secure FORM data to into a Single Page App. The flow of data is as follows

`www.foo.com` - static website containing a form

`spa.foo.com` - single page application in react/redux

www.foo.com contains

```
<form action="https://spa.foo.com/">
   username: <input type="text" name="username></input>
   password: <input type="password" name="password"></input>
</form>
```

Is there a way to securely send the password into React state or do I have to process it on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with "sending the password into react state"?
just use the setState function, the secure part will be done when you try to send the password to the other page, you should have a validaton on the backend and a token creation so in your `spa.foo.com` you will manage everything with this token instead of sending the user and password all the time.